# SQLDataSource FilterExpression not displaying default results

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a `FilterExpression` in my `SQLDataSource` set up so that I can enter a query in a text box and the relevant information is displayed in the `GridView`. To this extent, my code is working.

The problem I'm having is that no information is displayed until a search is made. In other words, when the page is first brought up, it is blank other than the search feature. I want the page to display everything at first, and then filter after a search is made.

It looks to me like my code is identical to code I find on the internet, but
for some mysterious reason, it is not displaying for me.

This is my code right now:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ABC" runat="server" DataSourceMode="DataSet" EnableCaching="true" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ABCConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [myDatabase]"
UpdateCommand="UPDATE [myDatabase] SET [xData] = @xData, [yData] = @yData, [zData] = @zData WHERE [myID] = @myID" 
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [myDatabase] WHERE [myID] = @myId" 
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [myDatabase] ([xData], [yData], [zData]) VALUES (@xData, @yData, @zData)" 
FilterExpression="xData LIKE '{0}%' "> 
<FilterParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="xData" ControlID="searchRecord" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="%"/>
</FilterParameters>
```

And then above my `GridView` I have the `TextBox` and `Button`:

```
<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Search" />
<asp:TextBox ID="searchRecord" runat="server" Text="Search by store number"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: This issue is still unresolved. I have attempted to make the FilterExpression an OnClick event, but the FilterExpression is not working as an OnClick event. Any suggestions? I have scoured the internet for a solution and I cannot find anything beyond what I already have, which isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by placing the filter in the button `onclick` and separately grouping the validation controls. Somehow the validation controls
were cross-firing and this was preventing the display.

I added `ControlToValidate="xyz"` to all of the `CompareValidators` corresponding to one set of controls (in my case, the controls for inserting a new row). Doing this grouped the controls for insertion separate from some of my other controls, and everything worked fine after that.